# Adding some but not all data from new app version’s database to existing database

Tags: ios, sql, xcode, core-data

I am creating a core data app with preloaded data using an SQL file. I am able to create the preloaded data, insert that SQL file into the project, and there is no problem. When users open the app for the first time the pre-populated store is copied over to the default store.

However, I am thinking ahead that in future versions I will want continue to add to this database. I will want users to be able download the current version with the latest DB without erasing user-generated data or user-edits to data in the preloaded DB.

This is not a migration issue because the model has not changed. Basically, when a new version of the app is opened for the first time I want it to check for the presence of new objects in the pre-populated store and add them to the user store. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your preloaded data include, for each object, the version where that object was first added to the preload file. Then add new data by

1. Look up the previous app version in user defaults. Compare it to the current version. If they're the same, stop, otherwise continue to the next step. (If there is no previous version number, continue to the next step).
2. Fetch all objects that were added more recently than the saved version number from step 1.
3. Add those objects to the user's persistent store.
4. Update the app version in user defaults so it'll be current next time.

You can do this check every time the app launches. You'll want to save a numeric version number in user defaults that will always increase in future versions of the app.

The simple way to record the version info in the preload file is just to add an extra field on each entity type. A more elegant way would be to create a new entity called something like `VersionWhereAdded` that includes a version number and a to-many relationship to objects added in that version.